# AesCryptoServiceProvider used to encrypt a zip can not be decrypted

Tags: c#, encryption

have used AesCryptoServiceProvider to encrypt a zip file with a password . 
but after the zip file produced it can not be decryted using winzip or winrar with same password.

can anyone suggest what is the problem?
Is winzip can not decrypt AesCryptoServiceProvider encryption ?

If so what are encryption class that support by winzip in .NET 4.5?

Comment: I don't know what you did, but I'm quite sure you didn't do the right thing. An encrypted zip file isn't a zip file which you encrypt wholly... It is a zip file "container" containing encrypted compressed files. So it is the contained compressed files that are encrypted. The contained is encrypted, not the container.

Comment: How did you encrypt the file? `AesCryptoServiceProvider` implements plain AES. It doesn't support passwords and it certainly doesn't use the encrypted zip format.

Comment: Yes xanatos You are correct to mention that inside a zip the files get encrypted ...which we all know

Answer (score 0):

Like the comment by xanatos correctly states you can't do this in the way you intend. I personally found DotNetZip to be a good solution for your problem.

[From their website](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/)

> Why would you want to produce yet another Zip Library?
>   There are a number of options in the .NET world for manipulating zip files. Some are commercial libraries, some are open-source. You can even shoe-horn the System.IO.Packaging API, which is included in .NET 3.0, into a zip library. But there are tradeoffs for all of them. Some people are willing to give up commercial support for a lower price. Some people don't like the GPL. Some of those other packages are complex to use for zip files. Some of them don't have enough features (Eg, AES encryption, ZIP64, zip spanning). Some are too slow. What I found is that most people want something simple and easy to use, that works well, has good features, compresses effectively and fast, and is the right price. DotNetZip is that option. It's fast, it's simple, it's free.

Comment: problem with DotnetZip is when You create a bigger size zip the extraction  do not work properly in windows

Comment: Could you link me a source for that? Because according to their documentation they support the same size limits as the zip-standard. Also what amounts of data are we talking about?